# Forward filling by column values in python polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I am wondering if there's a way to do forward filling by columns in polars because I tried the `fill_null(strategy='forward')` but it filled the null not with the next column value. What's the best way to achieve like `ffill()`

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": ["NY", "TK", "FD"], 
        "eat2000": [1, 6, 3], 
        "eat2001": [-2, None, 4],
        "eat2002": [None, None, None],
        "eat2003": [-9, 3, 8],
        "eat2004": [None, None, 8]
    }
); df

shape: (3, 6)
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ -9      ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 6       ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ 3       ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

df.fill_null(strategy='forward')

┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ -9      ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 6       ┆ -2      ┆ null    ┆ 3       ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

```
Expected result: 
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ -2      ┆ -9      ┆ -9      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 6       ┆ 6       ┆ 6       ┆ 3       ┆ 3       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ 4       ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new [`coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars.coalesce) Expression to fold columns horizontally.  If you place the `coalesce` expressions in a `with_columns` context, they will be run in parallel.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col("^eat.*$").cast(pl.Int64))
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.coalesce(["eat2004", "eat2003", "eat2002", "eat2001", "eat2000"]),
            pl.coalesce(["eat2003", "eat2002", "eat2001", "eat2000"]),
            pl.coalesce(["eat2002", "eat2001", "eat2000"]),
            pl.coalesce(["eat2001", "eat2000"]),
        ]
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 6)
┌─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ eat2000 ┆ eat2001 ┆ eat2002 ┆ eat2003 ┆ eat2004 │
│ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ NY  ┆ 1       ┆ -2      ┆ -2      ┆ -9      ┆ -9      │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ TK  ┆ 6       ┆ 6       ┆ 6       ┆ 3       ┆ 3       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ FD  ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ 4       ┆ 8       ┆ 8       │
└─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Couple of notes.

I first cast the `eatXXXX` columns to the same type.  (In the DataFrame constructor, `eat2002` is of type `Float64` because of the way Polars initializes an all-null column that is not supplied with an explicit datatype).

I've written out the list of `coalesce` Expressions for demonstration, but the list of expressions can be generated with a Python list comprehension.

```py
eat_cols = [col_nm for col_nm in reversed(df.columns)
            if col_nm.startswith('eat')]
(
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col("^eat.*$").cast(pl.Int64))
    .with_columns([
        pl.coalesce(eat_cols[idx:])
        for idx in range(0, len(eat_cols) - 1)
    ])
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am slightly surprised that there's no direct syntax to handle such task compared to Pandas ffill(). Maybe a new feature for future releases.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    df
    .transpose(include_header=True)
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.col(x).forward_fill() for x in df.transpose(include_header=True).columns
        ])
    .transpose(column_names=df.columns)[1:]
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.all().exclude("id").cast(pl.Int64)
        ]
    )
)
```